# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property (variable_name) of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to pick up the latitude and longitude by using the below code . I am getting both of it correctly as expected. but i am not able to assign the
retrieved latitude and longitude values to a variable and use it in another method (onUpload()).

```
export class latlonComponent implements OnInit {
    lat  :number;
    lon  :number;

constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(){

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        var error = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      console.log(error);
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      //console.log(position);
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;    //Getting error here as "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of null"
      this.lon = position.coords.longitude;     //Getting error here as "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lon' of null"
      console.log(this.lat);
      console.log(this.lon);

    };

    getLocation();




}

onUpload(){
    console.log(`Latitude ----> ${this.lat}`);  //Getting undefined here
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The below line,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

Needs to be changed as,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPosition' of undefined. It is giving me this error.

Comment: Remove function from `function showPosition(position)` and have it as `showPosition(position)`

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: showPosition is not defined . I tried that. it gives me this one.